# [react-native]Could not connect to development server and unable to symbolicate stack trace(android)

Tags: react-native

I am new react native.i am developing a app which includes json data fetching by using axios. I made development connection through usb to my pc and app works fine but when i unplug the usb or close the react packager then there is a red screen on start of my app that says could not connect to development server.and then there is a error below in yellow bar that says unable to symbolicate stack trace...how can i get rid of these errors and run my app independently ?

Comment: You have to shake your phone during connection, you will get popup on the screen -> click on the Settings ->select debug server host option-> enter your ip address like 10.0.0.0:8081, 8081 is default port, and disconnect your machine from cable

Comment: Do not close development server

Answer (score 2):

I think according to your question you are closing the development server from commandline or cmd.
Once you disconnect you will have to restart the packager.

Answer (score 0):

TO connect with Api

select the port number from API application url Example: http://localhost:44394

Step 1: Launch the emulator  using command in terminal    :     npx react-native run-android
Step 2: open the app in emulator:
Step 3: enter the command in root terminal: adb reverse tcp:44394 tcp:44394